# Is return value from a stored procedure must be declared as out parameter?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Consider a general scenario

I have a stored procedure which returns a specific value at the end. Do I need to explicitly mention it as out parameter? Or is the select statement enough to return the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct and call different types of stored procedures:

1) **A stored procedure that returns no result. For example, such a stored procedure can log non-critical information, or change database data in a straightforward way.**

> Example : A stored procedure which performs insert operation.

2) **A stored procedure that returns one or more values using output parameters. For example, such a procedure can indicate success or failure, or retrieve and return data items.**

> Example : A stored procedure which performs "Select particular_field
>   FROM table ..." query.

3) **A stored procedure that returns one or more result sets. The procedure can execute one or more queries, each of which returns an arbitrary number of rows. Your application loops through each result set to display, transform, or otherwise process each row in it.**

> Example : A stored procedure which performs multiple select queries.

Hope it might help.

Comment: So, the "particular_field " in select statement should be mentioned as out parameter?

Comment: yes. But you can use the second scenario like the third one if you don't want to use output parameters. In that case your stored procedure will return one result set.